# different appearance on different phones for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

We are getting ready to release an app, there is a slight difference in appearance on my development phones a Moto X and Galaxy Nexus, and my clients phones. He has a HTC One S with Android 4.4.4. Are there any websites or tools that I can test the appearance on for different phones? He lives in Brazil and me in Florida, so using his is out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse/ADT as your IDE?  If so, the layout editor provides different views for a handful of different devices.

I am having trouble attaching a screen shot, so I will just explain.  In the layout editor, you will see drop-down selectors for (a) Device/Screen Type, (b) Orientation, (c) Application Theme, (d) Android API level.  This provide reasonable previews of you layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Android Virtual Device for this. You can use whatever version of android you would like, there are tons of predefined device sizes/resolutions or if none of those suit your needs you could always define your own.